# Should I use Next.js to allow the application to be indexed by google?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, seo

I created a web application for a family business using react.js a few months ago but the website is only accessible by people who know the exact URL. It is using a firebase backend and a React.JS frontend.

I've used the google crawler checker and it returns normal saying that the crawlers are able to access the website with a screenshot of the page. However, it is not indexed on google search results.

I've read about how SSR is a possible solution to this using Next.JS.. but not really sure what it means. How can i get the website to show towards the top of the search results when the business name is searched in google? Should I use Next.JS over React.JS for something like this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the massive world of Search Engine Optimization.

There are many, infinite ways, to get your website to the top of the rankings on Google.  To name a few:

- Readable domain, look up how to put your website behind jtsapebusiness.com instead of weird-animal-123.firebase.etc.io.
- Serving certain files like robot.txt that Google specifically searches for
- Having Meta Tags
- Having specific Meta Tags for each page (Next JS is great for this)
- Render Time (Server Side Rendering is also great for this, but if your "React" app is small enough the performance difference shouldn't really matter to be honest.)
- Page accessibility, Google can scrape single page apps a lot better than it used to, but serving up each page individually via Sever Side Rendering has a lot of perks.
- How often your page is searched and clicked on (tell your friends and family to search you on google and click on your website)

These are just a few!  Reading more about Search Engine Optimization will help you come up with even more questions.  When and if you do switch to Next.js, you will still be using React.  You will just be writing it a little differently to fit a more server side pattern.

It will not matter much if you choose to pick between "React or Next".  If you wanted to maximize your chances of ranking higher, then I would go with Next.  But I wouldn't want you to pickup a whole new technology if you already have the React App built. Instead you would just need to add some Search Engine Optimization sprinkles on top (some examples listed above).